# Multiline SQLite in JupyterLab seems to be virtually unusable

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to use SQLite queries in JupyterLab. Virtually all multiline queries I try end up with an "unexpected indent" or "invalid syntax" error. Single-line queries seem to work fine, but multiline never works, with few, apparently random exceptions. Examples:

1. Single line, works as expected.

   ```
   %sql SELECT employee_id, last_name FROM employee
   ```
2. Multiline, unexpected indent.

   ```
   %sql SELECT employee_id, 
   last_name 
   FROM employee
   ```
3. Multiline, works. (Found the \ trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684494/jupyter-notebook-does-not-allow-me-to-type-mysql-queries-on-multiple-lines) on SO. It also says multiline should work with the %%sql magic, but it is not recognised as such.)

   ```
   %sql SELECT employee_id, \
   last_name \
   FROM employee
   ```
4. Multiline, but without querying last_name. Doesn't work, unexpected indent.

   ```
    %sql SELECT employee_id \   
    FROM employee
   ```

I've tried all sorts of variations of indent, it never works. I've tried triple quotes, parentheses, nothing works. If I can't make multiline queries, SQL is unusable in JupyterLab. It can't be so stupidly complicated, so I must be doing something wrong. Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. %%sql needs to be the *first* thing written in the cell. If there's even a comment before it (as it was in my case), everything breaks down as I illustrated above. That's odd anyway, because writing %%sql anywhere else will result in an error message saying that the %%sql line magic was not found.